# How do you find where an error has occurred in MIT scheme?

Tags: scheme, sicp, mit-scheme

When you get an error in MIT scheme it doesn't tell you where the error occurred. For example, it just prints something like this:

```
;Unbound variable: top-left
;To continue, call RESTART with an option number:
; (RESTART 3) => Specify a value to use instead of top-left.
; (RESTART 2) => Define top-left to a given value.
; (RESTART 1) => Return to read-eval-print level 1.
```

How do I find where this error occurred in my code?

Comment: It does, actually, tell you where the error is. It is telling you that `top-left` does not exist. You can search through your code to see where that is being referenced.

Comment: Yes, although if you reference top-left several times, then you don't know which one is causing the problem.

Comment: If it doesn't exist, then it would be the first reference.

Comment: it's pretty late but I'll just leave a comment here just in case someone need it. I got this same problem evaluating the Scheme code with `C-x-e` in `evil mode`. Turns out because I was in `normal mode` and `C-x-e` just evaluating the code before the cursor so it was missing the last parenthesis. So I just turn to `insert mode` and move the cursor to the last position and it worked like a charm. yeah I know, it's a newbie mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mit-scheme, if you are using the REPL from a shell, you can call [debug](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/stable/mit-scheme-user/Command_002dLine-Debugger.html)  to get the debugger. If you are using the edwin editor. It comes with it's own debugger. [Edwin debug.](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/stable/mit-scheme-user/Edwin-Debugger.html)
Neither will tell you the line of code in a file where the error occurred if that is what you want. But they provide plenty of information, and facilities to find the problem. Both links are to the Documentation with a good explanation on how to use them.