# How to get the file name and line number where an error occurred in MIT/GNU Scheme?

Tags: scheme, mit-scheme

I am working through SICP and I use the MIT/GNU Scheme 9.2 interpreter within Emacs. My programs now consist of multiple files that I load at once. If I make a syntactic mistake, I get an error message such as the following:

> Unbalanced close parenthesis: #)

Currently, I have to gradually eliminate lines in a file to find the source of the error. It would be a lot easier if I had the line number where the error occurred. Also, it would be preferable to get the name of the file along with the line number for clarity. Is there a way to get that information?

An online search and consulting the manual did not help. An [identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26947085/how-do-you-find-where-an-error-has-occurred-in-mit-scheme) exists, but the accepted answer does not actually answer the question. I would prefer to not switch to Edwin or DrRacket if it can be avoided.

Comment: I dont have an answer but I highly recommend using the paredit package for Emacs. It allows for structural editing. http://emacswiki.org/emacs/ParEdit Note: from what I can tell paredit jumps to the first sexp that has inbalanced parenthesis when you try to enable it `(M-x paredit-mode)`

Comment: How do you load the files all at once? Edwin is very similar to emacs. And if you are only editing files in it and evaluating them in mit-scheme I don't see why not use it. Geiser is also a good option. It works with Racket, guile and chicken. Using Geiser you can easily find the error. I did almost all SICP with edwin.